# Tengo un erro con sql server 2018, al momento de usar insert into

Tags: sql-server-2017

[image: ERROR DE INSERT INTO EN TABLAS CREADAS]

Tambien quiero agregar que he intentado ejecutar el codigo por partes para ver que pasa y aun asi me muestra el siguiente error que de igual manera esta en la imagen.

```
...L9AB3.sistema_facturacion (DESKTOP-DQL9AB3\jacka (52))* 1 Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 28 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int. The statement has been terminated.
(0 rows affected)
(0 rows affected)
(0 rows affected)
(0 rows affected)
(0 rows affected)
Completion time: 2020-04-03T17:49:52.4873330-05:00
```

Comment: Tu problema pasa por que estas intentando agregar un valor demasiado grande para un tipo de dato `INT`, por lo que deberías cambiar dicho tipo de dato a `BIG INT` por ejemplo

Comment: Huy amigo, mil gracias, me dejo una experiencia bastante grande.

Comment: Sencillo solo tengo que cambiar el tipo de dato, entonces doy por resuelto este post gracias.